# How can I have one plank on each of my monitors

Tags: release-loki, plank, display

In my freya setup, I had 2 planks, one for each of my monitors. I accomplished this by using the settings file in ~/.config/plank/dock[n]. This file is now missing. Is there any way to create another instance of plank and move it to my second monitor?

Answer (score 3):

You need either `dconf-editor` or command-line tool `gsettings`.

1. You can change the value of `net.launchpad.plank.enabled_docks` to `['dock1','dock2']` in order to enable a second dock,
2. restart plank,
3. change the preferences under `net.launchpad.plank.docks.dock2` to setup the second dock (you will need to change at least the `net.launchpad.plank.docks.dock2.monitor` value).

You will still need the `.config/plank/dock[n]` folders to store the launchers for each dock (you need to create them before restarting plank).

cf. [How to duplicate the taskbar on the second monitor on Loki?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9084/how-to-duplicate-the-taskbar-on-the-second-monitor-on-loki?rq=1)

Comment: I just noticed that the second question is a dupe, but since this one was wrongfully closed, it'd never received an answer.