# How to duplicate the taskbar on the second monitor on Loki?

Tags: release-loki, settings, display, plank

There are instructions how to do it previous versions of elementary OS but not for Loki. There is no setting file in the /home/.config/dock1 folder to edit. My monitors are not mirrored, they are extended. I want taskbar on both monitors.

Please help :)

Answer (score 2):

Setting is now done via gsettings. Install dconf-editor an go to net > launchpad > plank and change enabled-docks from ['dock1'] to ['dock1', 'dock2'] and run

```
 cp ~/.config/plank/dock1 ~/.config/plank/dock2
```

Now restart plank. If you change your docked apps often you might want to look into [syncing two folders](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203846/how-to-sync-two-folders-with-command-line-tools) You could come up with a command that syncs the folders and have it run on every reboot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if I link the dock1 items to dock2? Would that work?

Comment: I haven't tried, but I don't see why it wouldn't work. To create a symbolic link so the computer sees dock1 when pointed at dock2, delete the dock2 folder and run: ln -s ~./config/plank/dock1 ~./config/plank/dock2