# plank on three monitors using Juno 5.0

Tags: release-juno, plank

I've tried to set up plank on three monitors but without success.

I parsed these answers also: [How can I have one plank on each of my monitors](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7642/how-can-i-have-one-plank-on-each-of-my-monitors?rq=1), [How to duplicate the taskbar on the second monitor on Loki?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9084/how-to-duplicate-the-taskbar-on-the-second-monitor-on-loki?rq=1)

What I did:

**step1:**

> change settings in `dconf-editor` ==> `net.launchpad.plank.enabled_docks`: 
>   from `[dock1]` to `[dock1, dock2, dock3]`

**step2:**

> copy configs of the dock1 to the dock2 and dock3:

```
cp -r ~/.config/plank/dock1 ~/.config/plank/dock2
cp -r ~/.config/plank/dock1 ~/.config/plank/dock3
```

**step3:**

> restart plank: `sudo killall plank`

At the end I got nothing. I tried to log out but nothing was changed, only one plank on the main monitor was present.

Could you please explain how to do this on **Juno 5.0**? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Did you change the 'monitor settings' in net.launchpad.plank.docks.dock1/2/3 to different values?

Comment: @mazienho, it's the first described step above. Did you mean that?

Comment: No, in your settings you enable multiple docks - so far so good. Maybe you need to change settings for each dock in the config path I mentioned.

Comment: @mazienho, thanks for the reply. I do not have any files named 'monitor settings' in the path you mentioned. In this path ==> `/net/launchpad/plank/enabled-docks`  the only setting is `enabled-docks`. Nothing more in `plank` folder. Should I create 'monitor settings' file manually?

Comment: in my dconf editor there is this option [link](https://ibb.co/zQ0b98V)  Maybe that is missing in Juno? I still use Loki so I hoped that my comments could help you.   I do not know if I had hard problems but I cannot remember that I created these settings manually. Maybe they came with installation of "elementary tweaks"? Can you choose a display when you open "plank preferences" (right click on plank or `plank --preferences` in terminal)?

Comment: @mazienho, the thing that helped me to show three planks at once was just to add `[dock1, dock2, dock3]` to the `net.launchpad.plank.enabled_docks`. Then logout and here we have three planks on one monitor. But it is still unclear how to position that planks between monitors. Some monitor configuration is missing here and I don't know which one.